# sql query to display only unsold tender

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am having following tables:

Tender Master:

```
tenderid   tendername 
1           kjnj
2           hjbhb
3          abc
```

Bid Master:

```
bidid     tenderid       userid            status 
1          1             100            unsold
2          1             101            unsold
3          1             102            unsold
4          1             104            sold
5          2             100            unsold
6          2             101            sold
7          3             100            unsold
8          3             101            unsold
9          3             102            unsold
```

now i want to display only name of only those tender which are not sold ie unsold.

i want output like this:

```
tendername
abc
```

here only name of third tender will come as it is not sold to any one.
here tender 1 is sold to userid 104 so it will not come and tender 2 is sold to userid 101
so it will also not come.

i have written query like this:

```
select t.tendername 
from tender_master t,bid master b 
where t.tenderid==b.tenderid 
    and b.status=='unsold'
```

but it is giving me all the name of tender.

can anyone please provide me correct query??
please please.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: m using sqlserver2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
   tendername
FROM [Tender Master] TM
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      (
          SELECT 1 FROM [Bid Master] BM
          WHERE TM.tenderid = BM.tenderid
          AND BM.status = 'sold'
      )
```

Comment: sir can u please explain me your query??

Comment: your query worked successfully.thank u so much sir for ur kind help.thank u so much sir

Answer (score 2):

Try it with a single `=` instead of `==`.

Comment: problem is not dat.problem is there are multiple user bidding on tender and tender will be sold to only one user so it is giving me all the records

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to check if there is a status 'sold' in the tender group

```
SELECT   TenderName
FROM     TenderMaster TM
         INNER JOIN BidMaster BM ON TM.TenderID = BM.TenderID
GROUP BY TenderName
HAVING   SUM(CASE Status WHEN 'sold' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

If you are using Oracle change the last line to

```
HAVING   SUM(DECODE(Status, 'sold', 1, 0)) = 0
```

Comment: thank u so mcuh for ur kind help.thank u once again.your query worked successfully.